# Integration for Dirac-delta function

Tags: integration

Is there any way to solve the integration below? or make it simple to eliminate the Dirac-delta function?

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty m(x)\delta(G(x)-g_c)f_X(x)dx $$

where $f_X(x)$ is a probability density function (PDF) of random variable x.

It will be very helpful for any reference or clue to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: If $G$ is continuously differentiable you can essentially change variable to $y=G(x)-g_c$. In general $\delta(f(x)) = \sum_j \delta( x-x_j)/| f'(x_j)|$ where $x_j$ are the roots of $f(x)$.

Comment: You need to include some assumptions about $G$ and a motivation: why  would you want to compute such integrals, what is the context that led you tom this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to solve problems such as this is to Fourier transform: Call your function $f(g_c)$, then its Fourier transform
$$F(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(g_c)e^{i\xi g_c}dg_c=\int_{-\infty}^\infty m(x)f_X(x) e^{i\xi G(x)}\,dx$$ 
no longer contains the Dirac delta function. You can then recover $f(g_c)$ by an inverse Fourier transform,
$$f(g_c)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\xi)e^{-i\xi g_c}\,d\xi.$$
Whether or not this is doable in some closed form will of course depend on your choice of the functions $m$, $f_X$, and $G$.

Comment: I deeply appreciate your response. If I want to calculate the integration by the numerical way such as Monte Carlo simulation. I mean random sampling on PDF of x. What should I do? In addition, Could you explain the meaning of the equation you wrote? I cannot fully understand it.

Comment: @user136540  You have to be ca Dirac function is not a function, it is a *generalized* function. The next best thing you can do is approximate $\delta$ by a Gaussian with a a tiny, tiny variance.

Comment: Carlo Beenakker, @LiviuNicolaescu I believe the answer is simpler than that :).

Comment: @CarloBeenaker  You have to know that I, as a pure  mathematician, am a bit envious on theoretical physicists  that integrate  objects like $\delta(g(x))$  to  get spectacular  conclusions. To me  $\delta(g(x))$ is the pullback of a distribution which is a rather ill defined  operation, unless $0$ is a regular value of $g$. Suddenly I get worried. For my sanity I replace $\delta$ by a Gaussian with tiny variation and my worries disappear.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu To calculate the above equation in a numerical way, I also tried to replace $\delta$ as a Gaussian, but the magnitude of tiny variation have to be decided according to the number of samples for numerical integration. Could you tell me your suggestion to decide the tiny variation? any rule-of-thumb.

Comment: @LiviuNicolescu  The pullback of a distribution is not a rather ill defined object—-it was defined and studied in some detail in the 50‘s for the case where $g$ is a diffeomorphism by, amongst others, Heinz König and J. Sebastião e Silva. Using a standard localisation process („recollement des morceaux“), it can be extend to much more general situations.  Thus $\delta \circ \sin (x)$ is well-defined since we can find a covering of the real line by open intervals on each of which either the sine function is a diffeomorphism or it takes its values in an open interval on which $\delta$ is smooth.

Comment: @LiviuNicolescu

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu This implies that the formulae given here are perfectly valid provided the usual proviso „under suitable conditions on the functions“ is added. These can be made precise (and are less severe than some mentioned here) but I suspect that is not a major preoccupation of the OP. In order to use your method, one requires not just a rigorous definition but a result of the type: when $f$ converges in some distributional sense, then so does  £f\circ g$. Could you give a reference and precise statement for the one you are using?

Comment: @user131781. You gotta make up your mind.   You said below that $G$b is not a nice function? What do you mean by that. Without any specific   assumptions  tthe best  answer you can expect  goes along tthe lines  of another less known Heisenberg principle "You can say everything about  nothing and nothing about everything." This  is a math site. A bit of rigor  and precision is expected of you.

Comment: @user131781 Read  Chapter VI in volume 1 of Hormander's  4 volume opus on partial differential equations.  One can define the pullback of any smooth function  by any smooth map. For distributions you cannot do this in genera.l Hormander explains when this is possible   in terms of wave front sets.   This condition is trivial;ly satisfied when you pullback by submersions.   Beyond submersions you need to check Hormander's condition on wave front sets.

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu Reading Hörmander is always a pleasure and I have spent many hours doing so, even without being commanded to by you. However, since I pointed to a rigorous definition which has been around since the time when he was still a young student I don‘t see the relevance to my answer. Also I rather think that using his monograph for an elementary question in one variable calculus is a bit of overkill.

Comment: @user131781 The composition with a diffeomorphism  was know by Laurent Schwarz  since the 40s when he  created  the theory of distributions  and it is a rather trivial fact. (Change in variables formula)   If your G were a diffeomorphism you would not have asked the question on this site because you already knew the answer. What happens when G is not a submersion is more interesting and that is where  the reference to Hormander becomes relevant.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize Icv's comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(x)\delta(G(x)-g_c)\ dx=\sum_{x\in G^{-1}(g_c)}\phi(x)/|G'(x)|$ whenever $G$ is nice. Then apply to $\phi=mf_X$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, G is not a nice function, so that I should calculate it in a numerical way, random samplings for random variable X. I was able to obtain analytical sets satisfying above condition (roots of $G(x)$-$g_c$)

Comment: @user136540 If your problem is how to compute that "integral" numerically, there are certainly better answers. However note that (as Liviu Nicolaescu pointed out) if $G$ is not a "nice function" then your integral is not well defined. This has the practical meaning that if you try to compute that object with said methods you will get answers that will depend on the algorithm used, including errors.

Answer (score 0):

Having been disturbed by the nature of some of the comments here I have reluctantly decided to give an answer to this query.  Suppose that $G$ is a continuous function on the line and the equation $G(x)=g_c$ has at most a countable family $x_i$ of soltions (I am assuming that $g_c$ is a constant).  Assume further that for each $i$, there is an open interval containing $x_i$ on which $G$ is a diffeomorphism.  Then the integral above exists and is equal to $$\sum m(x_i) \frac 1{|G‘(x_¡)|}f_X(x_i).$$
This for continuous $m$ and $f_X$ for which the sum converges absolutely.  This result is perfectly rigorous and uses a precise definition for the composition of a distribution (in this case, the $\delta$-distribution) with a function. I might add that this mathematics has been available for sixty years.